# NSAttribute Doesn't Make Bold Swift

Tags: swift, uilabel, nsattributedstring

I am trying to make fullname bold with boldFullName func. But obviously, it does not make any change on it. I believe that casting to string is deleting mutableString features. How can I avoid it without returning NSAttributedString

```
class NewNotificationModel: Serializable {
var fromUser: NewNotificationFromUserModel!
 }

class NewNotificationFromUserModel: Serializable {
var name: String!
var lastName: String!
}

final class NewNotificationViewModel {

// MARK: Properties
var notificationModel: NewNotificationModel!

private(set) var fullName: String!
 init(notificationModel: NewNotificationModel) {
    self.notificationModel = notificationModel
    self.fullName = boldFullName(getFullName())

 private func getFullName() -> String {
    guard let fromUser = notificationModel.fromUser, let name = fromUser.name, let lastname = fromUser.lastName else { return "" }
    return name + " " + lastname
}

func boldFullName(_ fullname: String) -> String {
    let range = NSMakeRange(0, getFullName().count)
    let nonBoldFontAttribute = [NSAttributedString.Key.font:UIFont.sfProTextSemibold(size: 16)]
    let boldFontAttribute = [NSAttributedString.Key.font:UIFont.catamaranBold(size: 20)]
    let boldString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: getFullName() as String, attributes:nonBoldFontAttribute)
        boldString.addAttributes(boldFontAttribute, range: range)
    return boldString.mutableString as String
}
}
```

And I am using this fullname in table cell as below

```
class NewNotificationTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, Reusable, NibLoadable {
@IBOutlet weak var messageLbl: UILabel!
 messageLbl.text = NewNotificationTableViewCell.configureText(model: model)
```

My configureText func is

```
private static func configureText(model: NewNotificationViewModel) -> String {
    guard let type = model.type else { return "" }
    switch NotificationType.init(rawValue: type) {
    String(format:"new_notification.group.request.want.join.text_%@_%@".localized, model.fullName, model.groupName ?? "")
    case .mention?: return String(format:"new_notification.post.mention_%@".localized, model.fullName)
```

But those .fullName does not do anything about bolding fullName.

Edited as NSAttributedString but this gives error

```
 case .internalCommunicationMessage?: return NSAttributedString(format:("new_notification.announcement.text_%@".localized), args: NSAttributedString(string: model.groupName ?? ""))
```

with this extension.

```
public extension NSAttributedString {
convenience init(format: NSAttributedString, args: NSAttributedString...) {
    let mutableNSAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: format)

    args.forEach { (attributedString) in
        let range = NSString(string: mutableNSAttributedString.string).range(of: "%@")
        mutableNSAttributedString.replaceCharacters(in: range, with: attributedString)
    }
    self.init(attributedString: mutableNSAttributedString)
}
```

}

Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'NSAttributedString'

Comment: case .internalCommunicationMessage?: return NSAttributedString(format:"new_notification.announcement.text_%@".localized, model.groupName ?? "") is giving an error Extra argument in call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with this extension

```
 convenience init(format: NSAttributedString, args: NSAttributedString...) {
    let mutableNSAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: format)
    
    args.forEach { (attributedString) in
        let range = NSString(string: mutableNSAttributedString.string).range(of: "%@")
        mutableNSAttributedString.replaceCharacters(in: range, with: attributedString)
    }
    self.init(attributedString: mutableNSAttributedString)
}
```

I modified my switch cases as below

```
 case .internalCommunicationMessage?:
        let content = NSAttributedString(string:"new_notification.announcement.text_%@".localized)
        let gn = NSAttributedString(string: model.groupName ?? "", attributes: [.font: UIFont.sfProTextMedium(size: size),
                                                                                .kern: -0.26])
        return NSAttributedString(format: content, args: gn)
```

the changed return type of configureText

```
configureText(model: NewNotificationViewModel) -> NSAttributedString
```

deleted boldFullName function and changed fullName type back to String

and finally inserted as below to label.

```
messageLbl.attributedText = NewNotificationTableViewCell.configureText(model: model)
```

Answer (score 1):

String doesn't contain attributes, you do need to return a `NSAttributedString` from your function.

What you can do instead is assigning the *attributed string* to the `attributedText` property of your `UILabel`. Documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilabel/1620542-attributedtext)

Example (after updating your function to return a `NSAttributedString`):

```swift
messageLbl.attributedText = NewNotificationTableViewCell.configureText(model: model)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign `messageLbl.attributedText`

```
func boldFullName(_ fullname: String) -> NSAttributedString {
    let range = NSMakeRange(0, getFullName().count)
    let nonBoldFontAttribute = [NSAttributedString.Key.font:UIFont.sfProTextSemibold(size: 16)]
    let boldFontAttribute = [NSAttributedString.Key.font:UIFont.catamaranBold(size: 20)]
    let boldString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: getFullName() as String, attributes:nonBoldFontAttribute)
        boldString.addAttributes(boldFontAttribute, range: range)
    return boldString.mutableString
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is you are trying to give `attributedString` to `text` property which is not gonna effect on the `UILabel` . You must change some part of your code like :

```
private(set) var fullName: String!
```

to :

```
private(set) var fullName: NSMutableAttributedString!
```

And

```
func boldFullName(_ fullname: String) -> String {
let range = NSMakeRange(0, getFullName().count)
let nonBoldFontAttribute = [NSAttributedString.Key.font:UIFont.sfProTextSemibold(size: 16)]
let boldFontAttribute = [NSAttributedString.Key.font:UIFont.catamaranBold(size: 20)]
let boldString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: getFullName() as String, attributes:nonBoldFontAttribute)
    boldString.addAttributes(boldFontAttribute, range: range)
return boldString.mutableString as String
}
```

to:

```
 func boldFullName(_ fullname: String) -> NSMutableAttributedString {
let range = NSMakeRange(0, getFullName().count)
let nonBoldFontAttribute = [NSAttributedString.Key.font:UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 10)]
let boldFontAttribute = [NSAttributedString.Key.font:UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 30)]
let boldString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: getFullName() as String, attributes:nonBoldFontAttribute)
    boldString.addAttributes(boldFontAttribute, range: range)
return boldString
}
```

And last when you call use `attributedText` instead of `string`

```
 messageLbl.attributedText = ...
```